# How to use Fcm module Ionic 5

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Hello i am trying to install @ionic-native/fcm in my Ionic 5 Cordova project.

I used to do it in Ionic 3 and it worked fine.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
npm install --save @ionic-native/fcm@4
```

but now it doen't.

I build my project in ios just fine before i tried to install fcm.

Although the plugin exists in the plugins folder and the module on the mode_modules folder when i try to build i am getting this

```
 sudo npm install --save @ionic-native/fcm@4
 npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
 npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! While resolving: rovespier@0.0.1
 npm ERR! Found: @ionic-native/core@5.33.0
 npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic-native/core
 npm ERR!   @ionic-native/core@"^5.29.0" from the root project
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
 npm ERR! peer @ionic-native/core@"^4.11.0" from @ionic-native/fcm@4.20.0
 npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic-native/fcm
 npm ERR!   @ionic-native/fcm@"4" from the root project
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
 npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
 npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! See /Users/helena/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

i know its a coflict error but i dont know how to fix it. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ionic 5 you have to use latest version of [ionic native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm):

> npm install @ionic-native/fcm